# What is the mistake in this excel VBA range definition?

Tags: excel, vba, range

Im trying to program a vlookup-like function in excel VBA. In order to do that I need to manipulate range data so a range definition using cells() fits my interest best. But I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the first code that is working:

```
Function GLookUp2(a, b, P, Q, R)

    Dim S As Workbook

    Set S = Workbooks(P)

    Dim T As Worksheet

    Set T = S.Sheets(Q)

    Dim U As Range

    Set U = T.Range(R)

    GLookUp2 = Application.VLookup(a, U, b, False)
End Function
```

However this code doesn't seem to work.

```
Function GLookUp1(a, b, P, Q, i, j, k, l)

    Dim S As Workbook

    Set S = Workbooks(P)

    Dim T As Worksheet

    Set T = S.Sheets(Q)

    Dim U As Range

    Set U = T.Range(Cells(j, i), Cells(l, k))

    GLookUp1 = Application.VLookup(a, U, b, False)
End Function
```

Can you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: Protip: use *meaningful identifier names*, like `lookupSource`, `lookupColumn`, etc.. Thank yourself later. Also, declare an explicit type for them; `ByVal lookupSource As Range`, and give the function an explicit accessibility and a return type, too: `Public/Private Function {name}({args}) As {type}`

Comment: Many things could possibly go wrong. Are you getting any specific run-time error? Put a breakpoint (F9) on the first `Set` statement, then run the code line by line (F8) - which statement is blowing up, and what's the error?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon
Well, the only difference between the two programs is in the definition of the range. That kind of definition shown in the second prgram only works for me when  there are no workbook or worksheet variables present.

And thanks for the protip I will do it.

Comment: Nitpick: it's an *assignment*, not a *definition* - also it's near-impossible to tell what each parameter stands for, given they're all random single-letter identifiers without a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Set U = T.Range(Cells(j, i), Cells(l, k))
> ```

That's accessing a `Range` on sheet `T`, using two ranges from whatever the `ActiveSheet` is, because these two `Cells` calls aren't *qualified* with an explicit worksheet object.

In other words, it's doing this:

```
Set U = SomeSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i), ActiveSheet.Cells(l, k))
```

That's going to blow up whenever `ActiveSheet` isn't `SomeSheet`, or whenever `j`, `i`, `l`, or `k` is 0.

This would fix it:

```
Set U = T.Range(T.Cells(j, i), T.Cells(l, k))
```

Because now `Cells` is guaranteed to be pulling from the same worksheet object.

Side note, avoid single-letter variable names, *especially* lower-case `l`.

Comment: (Tangential question to your last point - so using `i` as a variable name is not recommended/best practice? Aw! I use it frequently for a quick counter, i.e. `For i = 1 to 10`)

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon
Thank you, Sir! So do you have any solutions to the problem? I need those variables.

Comment: @BruceWayne Without context, `i` (and *maybe* `j`, if you have nested loops) is the *only* acceptable single-letter variable name, *given a `For` loop*. In any other context, it's meaningless. And it's only meaningful in a `For` loop because using `i` as a "quick counter" has been a programming convention since the dawn of time. And even then, you'd declare it with an explicit type.

Comment: @MetaLogicianWannabe the solution is to use `T` to qualify the `Cells` calls. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon
Thanks again